# ResultSet's getString method returns ? (question marks) when the string contains multibyte characters

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nvarchar

The database is oracle 11gR2 and the charset of the database is AL32UTF8 and the column I'm trying to query is NVARCHAR2.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (oRS.next())
        {
            String s = oRS.getString(1);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

All the non-English multi byte characters are displayed as question marks. 
I tried replacing the getString with getBytes and tried converting the byte array to String with "UTF-8" charset, no luck.

My intention was not to print on the console, but I am embedding this list of strings to a HTML file (a list control ). Even there it displays the strings with question marks. The HTML page was encoded with ISO-8859-1

Comment: Is `AL32UTF8` the same as Java's `UTF-8`?

Comment: Does your console output font support the character?

Comment: I have printed to console just to illustrate. Am actually embedding this list of strings to a HTML file (a list control <select>). Even there it displays the strings with question marks. The HTML page is encoded with ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

I changed the html page's encoding to UTF-8 and it started working. So the problem was not with the JDBC.